# Call function in includes folder that have php file into another php file - Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

This is about the WordPress plugin.

I look at other people WordPress plugin has somewhat like this code:

example.php

```
<?php

    $display = get_option( 'display' );
    
    if(!defined('PLUGIN_DIR'))
        define('PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
    
    function init() {
      load_plugin_textdomain('example', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang' );
    }
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init');
    
    include(PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/display.php');

?>
```

and then there is includes a folder that has display.php

have code like this:
display.php

```
<?php

    function display(){
    
    //thecodes
    
    }
 ?>
```

I've tried this coded concept. From what I analyze, if I'm not wrong, this code for calling functions in display.php, call the function display(){} code

this is my structure:

```
>includes

>>functions.php

achan.php

index.php
```

and, this is my code look like:

achan.php

```
<?php

    $test = get_option('test');
    
    define(PLUGIN_DIR . dirname(__FILE__));
    
    
    include(PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/functions.php');
    
    function testing(){
        global $test;
        echo ($test);
    
    }
    add_action('bbp_theme_after_reply_author_details', 'testing');

?>
```

and in includes folder, have functions.php
my code like this:
functions.php

```
<?php

    function test(){
        echo "HELLO";
    }
 ?>
```

But not working. Is there any wrong with my codes? the Hello not displayed at bbp_theme_after_reply_author_details. or maybe there is a more efficient way to call a function in another folder PHP file? Thank you, web developer.

Answer (score 0):

You should call test somewhere in your code, Something like this:

```
<?php

    $test = get_option('test');
    
    define(PLUGIN_DIR . dirname(__FILE__));
    
    
    include(PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/functions.php');
    
    function testing(){
        global $test;
        echo ($test);
        
        // You should call test like this.
        test();

    
    }
    add_action('bbp_theme_after_reply_author_details', 'testing');

?>
```

Look at `test()` in `function testing()`